# Laravel + Vuejs: Make all text in a table row color red/text-danger

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using `v-if` and `v-else`. If the fine is > than 0 then the entire text inside the row must be red? How do we do this please?

My code below works but it's a mess. I don't know how to clean it. Or maybe there's a better way to do it?:

```js
                <tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id">
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.description}}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.description}}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.dateloaned | myDate }}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.dateloaned | myDate }}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.datedue | myDate }}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.datedue | myDate }}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.daterenewed  | myDate }}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.daterenewed  | myDate }}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.datereturned }}</span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.datereturned }}</td>
                    <td v-if="issue.fine > 0"><span class="text-danger font-weight-bold">{{ issue.fine }} </span></td>
                    <td v-else>{{ issue.fine }}</td>

                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set class based on some conditions. I would go with something like this :

```
                <tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id" :class="issue.fine > 0 ? 'text-danger font-weight-bold': ''">
                    <td>{{ issue.firstname}} {{ issue.lastname}}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.description}}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.dateloaned | myDate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.datedue | myDate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.daterenewed  | myDate }}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.datereturned }}</td>
                    <td>{{ issue.fine }}</td>

                </tr>
```

You can also go with :

```
<tr v-for="issue in issues" :key="issue.id" :class="{'text-danger font-weight-bold': issue.fine > 0}">...</tr>
```

check out classes docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: Wow. That is so cool. I tried your second solution and my code is now clean. Thanks a bunch!